# How to save a PDF form as a printable PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, forms, print-to-pdf

I was recently given a PDF form to fill out (a government form, of course). I need to fill this out and print it later, as I do not have a printer at home. The form does not open in other PDF viewers such as Evince and Chrome, but opens fine in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. However, I can't figure out how to save my filled out PDF form for later printing.

- If I click "Save", then it saves as a PDF, but without any of the form content.
- If I click "Print", there is no "Print to PDF" option. There is a "Print to File" checkbox under "Advanced", but that just gives me a PRN file which I don't know how to open.
- There is no "Export" or similar option that I could find.

Is it really impossible for a Adobe's own PDF reader to save filled-in PDF files?

Comment: It’s not impossible. It is entirely dictated by the creator of the PDF. I’m not sure what Acrobat Reader is going to do for you. Acrobat can modify the protection on the PDF file and if you need a password to do it you can easily remove the PDF password with online tools. But the short answer is the file is “protected” from doing the things you want to do.

Comment: Also check here: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/filling-pdf-forms.html#save_forms

Comment: You don't need a built-in print-to-pdf option.  Just load a pdf print driver and select it as the printer.